# JSF buttons doesn't send data to bean

Tags: jsf

I have some JSF page and some bean, in cae that it is editing curent ellement i use update otherwice i use save methods.

I tryed to debug and think methods on buttons never executes

Here is my JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Manage panel</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>Add/edit patient</h3>
        <h:form>           
            <c:set var="patient" value="#{manageBean.patient}" />
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="#{patient!=null}">
                    <p:panel id="panel1" header="Patient" style="margin-bottom:10px;">  
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="First  name" />  
                            <p:inputText id="firstName" required="true" value="#{patient.firstName}" />  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Family  name" />  
                            <p:inputText id="familyName" required="true" value="#{patient.familyName}" />  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Sex" />  
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="sex" value="#{patient.sex}">  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{manageBean.sex}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Birthday date" />  
                            <p:calendar value="#{patient.birthdayDate}" mode="inline" id="birthdayDate"/>  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Nationality" />  
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="nationality" value="#{patient.nationality}">  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{manageBean.nationality}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Adress" />  
                            <p:inputText id="adress" required="true" value="#{patient.adress}" />  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Phone number" />  
                            <p:inputMask id="phoneNumber" required="true" value="#{patient.phoneNumber}" mask="(999) 999-9999"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>  
                    </p:panel>  
                    <p:commandButton value="Update" type="submit" action="#{manageBean.update(patient)}" />  
                </c:when>   
                <c:otherwise>
                    <p:panel id="panel2" header="Patient" style="margin-bottom:10px;">  
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="First  name" />  
                            <p:inputText id="firstName" required="true" value="" />  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Family  name" />  
                            <p:inputText id="familyName" required="true" value="" />  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Sex" />  
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="sex" value="">  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{manageBean.sex}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Birthday date" />  
                            <p:calendar mode="inline" id="birthdayDate"/>  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Nationality" />  
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="nationality" value="">  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{manageBean.nationality}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Adress" />  
                            <p:inputText id="adress" required="true" value="" />  

                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Phone number" />  
                            <p:inputMask id="phoneNumber" required="true" value="" mask="(999) 999-9999"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>  
                    </p:panel>  
                    <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{manageBean.save(firstName, familyName, sex, birthdayDate, nationality, adress, phoneNumber)}" />  
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </h:form>      
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is my bean methods:

```
   public String update(Patient patient) {       
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(patient);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return "go_home";
    }

    public String save(String fitstName, String familyName, Sex sex, Date birthdayDate, Nationality nationallity, String adress, String phoneNumber){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Patient patient = new Patient();
            patient.setFirstName(fitstName);
            patient.setFamilyName(familyName);
            patient.setSex(sex);
            patient.setBirthdayDate(birthdayDate);
            patient.setNationality(nationallity);
            patient.setAdress(adress);
            patient.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            session.save(patient);            
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return "go_home";
    }
```

Comment: How is JSF supposed to know the values of the parameters you're sending to the action? You really are misunderstanding the parameters that you can pass to the `action` in an `UICommand`.

Comment: Isn't it take parameters from inputText?

Comment: Values in inputText are updated in the model in the `update model` phase of JSF. So, when you get to run the `save` method, `patient.getFirstName()` will already return the value you set in the inputText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once u give the value attribute in your input tags it ll directly bind the given values to the java class. Create the class variables in ur java class and bind the input tags. EX:- 
In your bean class create variables like

```
private String firstName
```

and create the getter and setter methods

```
<f:view>

    <h3>Add/edit patient</h3>

    <h:form>           
                <p:panel id="panel1" header="Patient" style="margin-bottom:10px;">  

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="First  name" />
                        <p:inputText id="firstName" required="true" value="#{manageBean.firstName}" />

                        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Family  name" />  
                        <p:inputText id="familyName" required="true" value="#{manageBean.familyName}" />  

                        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Sex" />  
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="sex" value="#{manageBean.sex}">  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{manageBean.sex}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>  

                        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Birthday date" />  
                        <p:calendar value="#{manageBean.birthdayDate}" mode="inline" id="birthdayDate"/>  

                        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Nationality" />  
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="nationality" value="#{manageBean.nationality}">  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{manageBean.nationality}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>  

                        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Adress" />  
                        <p:inputText id="adress" required="true" value="#{manageBean.adress}" />  

                        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Phone number" />  
                        <p:inputMask id="phoneNumber" required="true" value="#{manageBean.phoneNumber}" mask="(999) 999-9999"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                </p:panel>  
                <p:commandButton value="Update" type="submit" action="#{manageBean.update}" />  

                    </h:form>
```

Create a new jsp page and copy-paste these codes inside body tag. 
In your java class create the variables and getter setter methods. 
Update should be a method which returns a string.

Comment: Now simply u have to call the method in your command button.<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{myBean.save}" />

Comment: In your test give $ instead of # JSTL will take $ only. If there s any exception or error message provide it.

Comment: Why are you using `<f:view>`? Are you trying to answer a JSF 2 question with JSF 1.2 code? Note that OP's using [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijtu.html) and not JSP.